# In Google Analytics, how to get Queries and Landing Pages on the Dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm fairly new to Google Analytics and I can't figure out how to add Queries and Landing Pages to my Dashboard. The best I've done is add them to my Shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps try something like this when you click Dashboard > New Dashboard > Create Dashboard:

[image]

And then you can change the Dimension to whatever you want (Matched Search Query, Query Match Type, Landing Page, etc.).

Comment: I see now that if you choose Table type, I can choose Landing Page as a dimension and that works. However, when I choose Matched Search Query, I get no data.